# NSLocalNotification fire when i open the notification tray

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ios4

i am using the local notification in APP then i am in the running mode of the app and i open the notification tray to see the other notification then my app notification fire automatically but there is some time remaining to fire that notification..but it fire before the fire date that has been scheduled by me..can anybody help me to solve that problem